# Child Form Freezes when Main form runs

Tags: c#, .net, forms, timer

I have a C# .net application that I am writing.
 Currently there is a timer on the Main form that runs down from 800 seconds at the point the code gets ran.
 When the main form loads It spawns a second form with a second timer at 1800 seconds. When the main form runs and finishes it updates the timer on the second form back to 1800. If the timer for the second form ever reaches 0 it sends an email.

Basically I am running a watchdog timer with the second form.

The problem I have is when the code runs on the main form everything locks up until its done.

Here is the Second form code(Watch dog)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PGEN_v3
{
    public partial class WatchDog : Form
    {
       public static int counter = 0;
        public WatchDog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void btn_TestWatch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                string strFrom = "PGEN@xxxxx";
                string strTo = "xxxx@xxxx";
                string strSubject = "xxxx";
                string strBody = "xxxx";
                Form1.sendEmail(strFrom, strTo, strSubject, strBody);

        }

        private void WatchDog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                       
            this.ControlBox = false;
            counter = 1800;
            lbl_WATCHCOUNT.Text = counter.ToString();
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            timer1.Start();

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter--;
            lbl_WATCHCOUNT.Text = counter.ToString();
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                string strFrom = "PGEN@xxxxx";
                string strTo = "xxxx@xxxx";
                string strSubject = "xxxx";
                string strBody = "xxxx";
                Form1.sendEmail(strFrom, strTo, strSubject, strBody);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the main form code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PGEN_v3
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        int counter = 0;
        public Form2()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            counter = 800;
            lbl_MainCounter.Text = counter.ToString();
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void Button_Scan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        //RUN CODE
counter = 800;
watchdogform.counter = 1800;
        }


        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                Button_Scan_Click(sender, e);
            }
            counter--;
            lbl_MainCounter.Text = counter.ToString();


        }
    }
}
```

How can I get he second form to spawn a different thread and it not lockup the child? 
 It also locks up the count down timer on the main form until the code is done. 
 My example code might not 100% work since I just pulled out bits an pieces from the actual working code. It should give you the idea though.

Here is a single example. Doesn't even involve a second form. 
When the timer hits 0 the scan starts. I want the timer counter to keep counting down. It freezes until the scan() is complete. You need two labels, a Timer and a list box. It checks to see if the path is valid for like 20,000 different paths. The scan takes about 7 minutes to complete.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml;
using System.Threading;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {   int counter = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            counter = 6;
           label2.Text = counter.ToString();
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            timer1.Start();

        }

        private void Scan()
        {
            DataTable table = GetProjects();
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {

                String PN = row["ProjectNumber"].ToString();
                string PATH = GetPath100(PN, "R:\\");
                bool PATHCHECK = !Directory.Exists(PATH);
                while ( PATHCHECK)
                { 
                    label1.Text = PATH.ToString();
                    listBox1.Items.Add(PATH); 
                }
            }

        }


        public static DataTable GetProjects()
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();


                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=user;Password=passwd");
                string query = "Select ProjectNumber, ProjectManager, Date  FROM [ProjMgt].[dbo].[tblProjectInfo]  where  ISNUMERIC(projectnumber) = 1 and len(ProjectNumber) >= 6 order by CAST(ProjectNumber AS int)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter dt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);


                dt.Fill(dataTable);
                return dataTable;

        }

        public string GetPath100(String PN, String STORAGEPATH)
        {
            int TENS = (Int32.Parse(PN) / 10) * 10;
            int HUNDREDS = (Int32.Parse(PN) / 100) * 100;
            int THOUSANDS = (Int32.Parse(PN) / 1000) * 1000;
            //PATH = TENS.ToString;
            String PATH = STORAGEPATH + "" + HUNDREDS + " JOBS\\" + TENS + " JOBS\\" + PN;
            //Console.WriteLine("R:\\" + HUNDREDS + " JOBS\\" + TENS + " JOBS\\" + PN);
            return PATH;

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                Scan();
            }
            counter--;
            label2.Text = counter.ToString();


        }
        }


    }
```

Thanks

Comment: There's no fundamental reason you should have any trouble showing both forms and running both timers concurrently. They all run in a single thread, cooperatively. If you are having problems with any of them not responding, then most likely you have some code that is blocking the UI thread. But you didn't show that code here. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: Ok I will produce an example tomorrow.

Comment: Ok I added a simple example at the bottom of the post.

Comment: `Form1.sendEmail` looks like a strong candidate for something that could be freezing things up.  You didn't show that code, but there might be a time-out issue with the email server you are using.

Comment: In my Simple example Peter asked for. I removed the send mail and made it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out from someone else on a different forum. I needed to run the portion of the code doing the work in a separate thread.

I added this in the timer section.

```
new Thread(() =>
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
                    /* run your code here */
                    Scan();
                }).Start();
```

Then I had to add

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                lbl_MainCounter.Text = counter.ToString();
                WatchDog.counter = 1800;
            });
```

Around anything that needed to be updated on the parent thead UI.

Thanks for the help.